# Is 100 or less requests per second (for non-cached pages) what one can expect with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scalability, benchmarking

**Preface:  Please don't start a discussion on premature optimization, or anything related.  I'm just trying to understand what kind of performance I can get from a single server with rails.**

I have been benchmarking ruby on rails 3 and it seems the highest rate of requests per second I can get is around 100 requests per second.

I used phusion passenger with nginx, and Ruby 1.8.7.

This is on a ec2 m1.large instance:

```
7.5 GB memory
4 EC2 Compute Units (2 virtual cores with 2 EC2 Compute Units each)
850 GB instance storage
64-bit platform
I/O Performance: High
API name: m1.large
```

The page was a very simple action that wrote a single row into mysql.

```
user = User.new
user.name = "test"
user.save
```

I am assuming no caching (memcache, etc), I just want to get a feel for the raw numbers.

I used apache bench on the same ec2 instance, and I used varying levels of # of requests (from 1000 to 10000 and varying numbers of concurrent requests 1/5/10/25/50/100).

Comment: Well, if you already ran the tests and you're not interested in optimizations, what's the actual question?

Comment: On a dedicated server (Ubuntu 11.04, Dual Xeon E5620's, 12GB RAM) running Unicorn (8 workers) behind nginx, I get around 1,200 requests/sec (on a page with no database hits).

Comment: @Dylan thanks!, I know Phusion passenger automatically scales to more workers behind the scenes, maybe it didn't kick in for some reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EC2 `m1.large` instance is really not that fast, so these numbers aren't surprising. If you want performance, you can either spring for a larger instance, as there are now some with 80 ECUs, or try a different provider.

I've found that [Linode](http://linode.com/) generally offers higher performance for the same price, but is not as flexible and doesn't scale to very large numbers of servers as well. It's a much better fit if you're in the "under 20 servers" phase of rolling out.

Also don't think that MySQL is a no-cost operation.

Comment: thanks for the advice, on the same instance type I was getting over 1K with java (doing the same inserting 1 row to mysql)

Comment: Why not try benchmarking using JRuby instead, then? That's easy to install using [rvm](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). You also have other options beside strict Rails, which is a programmer-speed friendly framework, such as Sinatra or plain Rack which is a performance-friendly framework.

Comment: this was more to understand the potential with rails, I know obviously there are faster solutions just wanted to get an idea of what to expect and what others have experienced (in case I was doing something wrong in my benchmark).

Comment: see the section on performance optimizations on the [padrino blog](http://www.padrinorb.com/blog/padrino-0-9-10-released-built-for-speed) where they compare several frameworks